# JdbcRowSet not recognizing MariaDB driver

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, mariadb, rowset

Under the same package of a Project, I have two classes. The classes are part of JDBC exercises. I am using **MariaDB 10.1.14**.

**Class1**

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test";
String uName = "root";
String pWord = "admin";
try{
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, uName, pWord);
    System.out.println(connection.isValid(100));
}catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which outputs `true`

**Class2**

```
String url = "jdbc://mariadb://localhost:3306/test";
String user = "root";
String pass = "admin";

try(JdbcRowSet rowSet = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createJdbcRowSet()){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM employee";
    rowSet.setCommand(query);
    rowSet.setUrl(url);
    rowSet.setUsername(user);
    rowSet.setPassword(pass);
    rowSet.execute();

    while(rowSet.next()){
        System.out.println(rowSet.getString(1));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which outputs

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc://mariadb://localhost:3306/test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.connect(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.prepare(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:654)
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.execute(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:556)
    at com.my.project.demotwo.jdbc.RowSet001.main(RowSet001.java:21)
```

The **pom.xml** has dependencies for MariaDB.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried looking around with the problem. But, most people seem to report it with `DriverManager`.

Has anyone had this problem with `RowSet` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `jdbc://mariadb://` instead of `jdbc:mariadb://` in the connection string.